# How to put a copy of an array into a new array in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array and now I want to create a copy of that array so that I can retain the previous values of my array if I want to.

I tried something like this:

```
System.arraycopy(firstArray, 0, secondArray, 0, firstArray.length);
```

But it is giving me a `NullPointerException`, i.e.:

```
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.iweentravel/com.android.iweentravel.MainAcvtivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: dst == null
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: dst == null
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at com.android.iweentravel.MainAcvtivity.onCreate(MainAcvtivity.java:99)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
08-26 13:20:08.421: E/AndroidRuntime(23739):    ... 11 more
```

Please suggest how I could properly create a copy of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Very simple Try this**

```
String arr2[] = arr1.clone();
```

Answer (score 2):

As the exception stands you have not allocate memory for the destination. Before System.arrayCopy call

```
secondArray = new String[first.length]
```

if `secondArray` is of the String type. Otherwise you have to change it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the exception you get, I'd say the secondArray parameter is null.

You can copy any array by simple "cloning it", like so:

String[] copy = orig.clone();

It will construct a new array, with a new set of pointers. This will allow you to modify the new array, without disturbing the original.

Note that, when your array contains objects, that the array CONTENT is NOT copied. The new array simply is a new set of pointers pointing to the same data. Observe:

```
Object[] a1 = new Object[3];
a1[0] = objectA;
a1[1] = objectB;
a1[2] = objectC;
Object[] a2 = a1.clone();
```

a2[0] now points to the exact same object instance as a1[0]. So if you were to modify something in the object pointed to be a2[0], you WILL in effect alter to object pointed to by a1[0].

If you do not want this either, you'd have to do something like:

```
Object[] a2 = new Object[a1.length];
for (int n=0; n<a1.length; ++n)
  a2[n] = a1[n].clone();
```

which will result in a so called deep-copy of the array a1.

Also note that this problem does not arise in the case of String arrays, as Strings are immutable.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] secondArray = new String[first.length]

for(int i=0; i<firstArray.length; i++){
   secondArray[i]=firstArray[i]
}
```